# Помогите разобраться, несколько модал окон на одной странице!

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У нас есть 8 блоков с картинками, нажимаешь на блок с картинкой и появляется определенное модальное окно, и так при нажатии на каждый блок что бы появлялся определенное модал окно !

```
<h2><b>PUPPIES FOR SALE: OLD ENGLISH SHEEPDOG 3 BOYS!</b><h2>
<div class="cnt">
<div class="boys">
          <div class="boystabl open-modal-btn" data-open-modal="modal1"><img src="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/m10-2.jpg" alt="альтернативный текст"><h3 class="textboystabl">Мальчик - 1 - Ищет любящую семью!<h3></div>
          <div class="boystabl open-modal-btn" data-open-modal="modal2"><img src="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/m10-2.jpg" alt="альтернативный текст"><h3 class="textboystabl">Мальчик - 2 - Ищет любящую семью!<h3></div>
          <div class="boystabl open-modal-btn" data-open-modal="modal3"><img src="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/m10-2.jpg" alt="альтернативный текст"><h3 class="textboystabl">Мальчик - 3 - Ищет любящую семью!<h3></div>
</div>
</div>

МОДАЛ ОКНО:

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="content">
      <a class="close-modal">
      МОДАЛ СОЖЕРЖИМОЕ №1
      <hr>
      <button id="close_modal">
        Закрыть
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>



<div id="wrapper1">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="modal1">
    <div class="content1">
      <a class="close-modal">
      СОДЕРЖИМОЕ МОДАЛА №2
      <hr>
      <button id="close_modal">
        Закрыть
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Jquery

```
 jQuery(function($){
    var wrap = $('#wrapper'),
      btn = $('.open-modal-btn'),
      modal = $('.cover, .modal, .content'),
      close = $('#close_modal'),
     close1 = $('#close_modal1'),
      state = {
        "close": 0
      };

    btn.on('click', function() {
      modal.fadeIn();
    });

    $('.modal').click(function() {
      wrap.on('click', function(event) {
        var select = $('.content');
        if (!$(event.target).closest(select).length && !state.close)
          modal.fadeOut();
        state.close = 0;
        $(this).unbind('click');
      });
    });

    close.on('click', function() {
      modal.fadeOut();
      state.close = 1;
    });

    close1.on('click', function() {
      modal.fadeOut();
      state.close = 1;
    });

    });
```

Comment: А содержимое окна... простое текстовое описание, или хитрый HTML с цветами, ссылками и прочим?

Comment: Извини сразу не сообразил ))

Comment: Там хитрый html будет, ща закину какой!

Comment: В общем не хватает символов что бы закинуть, в модал окнах там будет описание, ссылки, галерея фото

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хмм... ну я думал как-то упростить, но видимо не получится. По сути задача сводится к простым табам. Предложил бы хотя бы разместить каждое окно рядом со своей картинкой, чтобы в будущем легче было редактировать (заранее сделав окна невидимыми).

А все эти data-modal и id - создают лишнюю работу в данном случае. Можно обойтись одними лишь классами.

[убрал картинки, оставил только механизм. Покликайте]

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open-modal-btn', function(){
  $('.modal').eq( $(this).index('.open-modal-btn') ).fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
  top: 0; text-align: center; 
  display: none; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: red;
}

.close { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; color: red; font-size: 30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="open-modal-btn">Первая картинка</div>
<div class="modal">Хитрое описание 1111
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>

<div class="open-modal-btn">Вторая картинка</div>
<div class="modal">Хитрое описание 2222
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>

<div class="open-modal-btn">Третья картинка</div>
<div class="modal">Хитрое описание 3333
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>
```

Подробно о подобных переключениях [Описано здесь (с примерами)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-css/982073#982073)

Comment: Если нужно я могу содержимое модала закинуть!

Comment: Сейчас буду тестировать у себя и отпишусь!

Comment: @Coffee Kyiv Ну в данном случае нет разницы, что там внутри. Просто если описание короткое, обычно его можно прописать хоть в том же `data-bubu="описание"` - - и при клике на картинку, в одном и том же модале просто переключать значение-описание... собрав дату из текущего кликнутого элемента... (p.s. здесь под кодом есть кнопка "выполнить код" - она обеспечивает демонстрацию на месте)

Comment: Отлично, все работает )) Спасибо тебе большое !!

Comment: А при клике вне модального окошка, как сделать что бы окно закрывалось ?

Comment: $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".modal");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});

Comment: @Coffee Kyiv , Было бы легче сделать так - - https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/r6049g7a/ , само окно раскрыто на весь экран с 100 vw / vh, а описание - в блоке с ограниченными пикселями (там первые 2 строки text в CSS обеспечивают его центрирование). Тогда можно и кнопку-"крестик" не записывать, а закрывать модальное окно при клике на него самого, но убрать срабатывание закрывашки, когда клик произведен по главному описанию - `preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

Ну да все эти open-modal-btn и т.д. ващще не то, правильно сделал что сделал модалки невидимыми и заюзал классы! Молодец!

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open-modal-btn', function(){
  $('.modal').eq( $(this).index('.open-modal-btn') ).fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
  top: 0; text-align: center; 
  display: none; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: red;
}

.close { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; color: red; font-size: 30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="open-modal-btn">Первая картинка</div>
<div class="modal">Хитрое описание 1111
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>

<div class="open-modal-btn">Вторая картинка</div>
<div class="modal">Хитрое описание 2222
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>

<div class="open-modal-btn">Третья картинка</div>
<div class="modal">Хитрое описание 3333
  <button class="close">x</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо ребята!! Очень помогли )